# Should Google Analytics event tracking fire an XHR request?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-analytics, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to set up [Google Analytics event tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html). This is my code:

```
var uid = getUUID();
function postGA() { 
    var sliderval = $("#slider-stock").slider("value");  
    _gaq.push('_trackEvent', uid, sliderval); 
}
```

I'm noticing that when `postGA()` is fired, Firebug does not log an XHR request.

Is this normal, or should I expect to see one? If the latter, is there something obviously wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might see a request if the event tracking code was correct. See the [Event Tracking Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#Anatomy)

Try:

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', uid, sliderval]);
```

Install Chrome and the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna). Look in the console (control, shift, j) for the event tracking processing.

[image]

If you don't see your events tracking there, then something is up with the tracking code on the page.

Comment: You rock! - the Analytics Debugger let me see what was going on, and the suggested code fix made the event fire. (Even with the correct code, I didn't see an XHR request in the Console, so the Analytics Debugger was really helpful.) Thanks SO much.

Answer (score 1):

I think it loads in the Analytics tracking pixel - I can see it loading on my site in Inspector (resources view). It's called `__utm.gif`

The query string parameters appended to the gif are described at:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsOverview.html#gifParameters

Answer (score -1):

This page should give you a good idea of how analytics works.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsOverview.html